# Excel: Consider only cells with given value - Recursive formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to make a formula that lets me easily extrapolate a quality within a subser
Let's say I have the following set of data:

```
Week    Name    Accepted?   Accept Week?
1   a   TRUE    
1   b   TRUE    
1   c   TRUE    
2   d   FALSE   
2   e   TRUE    
2   f   TRUE    
3   g   FALSE   
3   h   FALSE   
3   i   FALSE
```

Three weeks, three entries each
I'm trying to make a formula that fills Column 4:
Week 1 would be TRUE because all three entries (B2:B4) are accepted week TRUE
Week 2 has a non accepted entry, therefore all three entries (B5:B7) are FALSE
Week 3 is false as well in Accept Week (B8:B10)

I would appreciate any tip you can give to me.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck at?

Comment: Tried playing around with INDEX and MATCH, but @ScottCraner 's did the work

Comment: The following formula would work to sum the booleans into the true and false results you would like for Accepted: =IF(SUM(--C2:C4)=1,TRUE,FALSE) 

you would need to do a lookup to get the range C2:C4 Boolean values as a result set and replace that in the IF statement above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,C:C,TRUE) = COUNTIF(A:A,A2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this did the job :)

Comment: @BaldomeroPajitziev please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.